# DispatchGroup doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have made a `DispatchGroup` and run 2 async tasks. One is on `main` and the other one is on `global()`.

As long as I understand, `DispatchGroup.notify`'s block should invoked once all tasks are done but it doesn't work as I thought.

```
class Que {
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    init() {
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("group done")
        }
    }

    func run() {
        doC()
        doD()
    }

    fileprivate func doC() {
        group.enter()
        DispatchQueue.main.async(group: group) {
            var rst = 0
            for idx in 0 ..< 500 {
                rst += idx
            }
            print("work item c is done")
            self.group.leave()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func doD() {
        group.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().async(group: group) {
            var rst = 0
            for idx in 0 ..< 50 {
                rst += idx
            }
            print("work item d is done")
            self.group.leave()
        }
    }
}
```

The result is

```
work item d is done
group done
work item c is done
```

I want to know why it is not

```
work item d is done
work item c is done
group done
```

If I made `C` and `D` task run on `global()` queue, it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put the call to `notify` in the wrong place and called it far too early.

Most likely you want to call `notify` at the end of your `run` method.

```
init() {
}

func run() {
    doC()
    doD()

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("group done")
    }
}
```

Note what is says in the documentation for the `notify` method:

> Schedules a work item to be submitted to a queue when a group of **previously** submitted block objects have completed.

The bold is mine.

Comment: So it is not work like usual callback closure. I thought if I set it once, it will be called everytime taks in the group done. Thanks!

Comment: It's called when there are no current tasks on the queue (after the last call to `leave` is made for any currently entered tasks).